# Incorrect call an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

```
  const [clientIfFromSearchWebitel, setClientIfFromSearchWebitel] = useState(
    undefined
  );


    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('clientIfFromSearchWebitel', clientIfFromSearchWebitel);
    if (clientIfFromSearchWebitel && clientIfFromSearchWebitel !== undefined && clientIfFromSearchWebitel !== '') {

      axios
      .post('https://extapi.megabank.ua/dev/ops/api/v1/getEntity/CASES', {
        filters: [
          {
            comparison: 'eq',
            fieldName: 'client_id',
            fieldValue: clientIfFromSearchWebitel
              ? clientIfFromSearchWebitel
              : undefined,
            operation: 'OR',
          },
        ],
      })
      .then(data => setFilterData(data.data));
    }else {
      axios
      .post('https://extapi.megabank.ua/dev/ops/api/v1/getEntity/CASES', {
        filters: [],
      })
      .then(data => setFilterData(data.data));
    }

  }, [clientIfFromSearchWebitel])
```

[image]

I have a clientIfFromSearchWebitel state, and when the component first appears, this state is undefined, when the component is updated again, the value is written to it based on which the API should be called, but the API is called instead of 1 time - 2 times, due to the fact that the 1st once the state is undefined 2nd with a value, how can this situation be fixed?

Comment: What do you want to fix here?

Comment: To fix it, make a single call, you making two calls with this logic

Comment: @HarishSoni API call again due to undefined status value.

Comment: @DennisVash Due to the fact that the state changes, the API is called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates

```
const fetchNow = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (fetchNow.current) {
    // do fetch now -- your existing code
  }
});
```

Where ever you are doing `setClientIfFromSearchWebitel()` replace with `fetchNow.current = true`

This way you can avoid useState and having conditions in useEffect.